# Задание количества знаков после запятой

Tags: c#, округление

Есть переменная типа double d=0,12312332453. Подскажите, пожалуйста - как задать вывод в консоли заданного количества знаков после запятой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как округлить число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502659/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, с помощью форматирования строки через String.Format(string, object). Console.WriteLine(string, object) то же самое, только сразу в консоль показывает.

Следующий код показывает число и 2 знака после запятой:

```
double d = 0.12312332453;
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.##}", d);
```

Comment: этот метод не вернет три знака после запятой в числе 1.5997, а округлит его до 1.6. Есть ли способ вернуть именно 1.599?

Answer (score 5):

```
double num = 321.345678;
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", num); // выведет два знака после запятой
```

Comment: На самом деле, если нужно действительно фиксированное количество знаков после запятой, этот вариант ответа лучше: http://ideone.com/hpfn3M

Comment: спасибо, буду знать)