# Как округлить число

Tags: c#, округление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как округлить 2 элемент массива до вида 3 элемента массива.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 14):

Они и так находятся в одном и том же виде. Просто у третьего элемента в конце нули, поэтому они не отображаются.

А так округлять можно с помощью метода `Round` класса `Math`:

```
Math.Round(double value, int digits);
```

- *value* - число, которое нужно округлить.
- *digits* - количество цифр в дробной части, которые нужно оставить.

Про перегрузку `Math.Round(value)` и про методы `Math.Floor(value)`, `Math.Ceiling(value)` и `Math.Truncate(value)` ничего говорить не буду, т.к. они Вам не подходят, все они округляют до целого.

Если Вам нужно округление для красивого вывода, то лучше использовать [строку стандартных числовых форматов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) с описателем ***N*** или ***F***, которые выводят число в нормальной записи (с плавающей точкой) с указанием точности:

```
double value = -123.45678;
string strA = value.ToString("N");   // "-123.46" В зависимости от NumberDecimalDigits (см. ниже)
string strB = value.ToString("N2");  // "-123.46"
string strC = value.ToString("N10"); // "-123.4567800000"
```

Число, стоящее после N, указывает на точность. Число называется *описателем точности*. Если числа нет, то число знаков после запятой определяется значением `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits`:

```
    Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalDigits); // У меня выводится 2
```

У меня `NumberDecimalDigits` = 2. Поэтому в предыдущем коде `strA = "-123.46"`.

Можно также для вывода использовать [строку настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)  с описателем ***0*** или ***#***, в зависимости от необходимого результата.

- ***0*** - говорит, что здесь должна стоять цифра. Если в числе нет соответствующей цифры, то в результирующей строке *останется стоять* этот 0.
- ***#*** - говорит, что здесь должна стоять цифра. Если в числе нет соответствующей цифры, то в результирующей строке *на этом месте ничего не будет*.

Покажу на предыдущем примере.
Если использовать ***0***:

```
double value = -123.45678;
string strA = value.ToString("0");   // "-123"
string strB = value.ToString("0.00");  // "-123.46"
string strC = value.ToString("0.0000000000"); // "-123.4567800000"
```

Если использовать ***#***:

```
double value = -123.45678;
string strA = value.ToString("0");   // "-123"
string strB = value.ToString("0.##");  // "-123.46"
string strC = value.ToString("0.##########"); // "-123.45678"
```